# Difference between std::merge and std::inplace_merge?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

What is the difference between `std::merge` and `std::inplace_merge` in terms of complexity and result when it is executed on two consecutive ranges with elements that are all different ? (I am not a native english speaker and I am not sure to clearly understand what "inplace" means)

Comment: in place basically means without permanently allocating memory for a new output range. (under the covers, there will be a temporary buffer, but this is  unobservable to users).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looking at the references for [std::merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) and [std::inplace_merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) you see the following complexities:
For `std::merge`:

> At most std::distance(first1, last1) + 
>   std::distance(first2, last2) - 1 comparisons.

And for `std::inplace_merge`:

> Exactly N-1 comparisons if enough additional memory is available,
>   otherwise N·log(N) where N = std::distance(first, last).

The `if enough additional memory is available` has a very specific meaning, from the notes on that page:

> This function attempts to allocate a temporary buffer, typically by calling
>   std::get_temporary_buffer. If the allocation fails, the less efficient 
>   algorithm is chosen.

`std::get_temporary_buffer` allocates memory dynamically (this is important to know if you wanted to use `std::inplace_merge` in a tight loop or have constrained memory requirements).

Lastly, the reference pages don't mention this (**edit**: cppreference has been updated as per the comment below), but in `std::merge` I don't think `d_first` can can overlap either of `[first1, last1)` or `[first2, last2)`.  This means that `std::merge` must output into a different range than either input ranges.
It also means the following call (for some `RandomAccessContainer` `a`):

```
    std::inplace_merge(a.begin(), a.begin() + n, a.end());
```

is not equivalent to:

```
    std::merge(a.begin(), a.begin() + n,
               a.begin() + n, a.end(), a.begin());
```

because you can't output into `a` if you're reading from it.  You would need:

```
    decltype(a) b;
    std::merge(a.begin(), a.begin() + n,
               a.begin() + n, a.end(),
               std::back_inserter(b));
```

for example.

Interestingly, [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/?kw=merge) states that the ranges shall not overlap (just above the return value section) which seems more strict than necessary because it means that the two input ranges also shall not overlap.  Furthermore, in the data races section it quite clearly states that the two input ranges are only accessed, so this slightly contrived (artificial) example:

```
    std::merge(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
```

would be illegal according to that, but I'm not convinced.  Neither of these references are the standard, and unfortunately I don't have a copy of it to reference myself, but perhaps someone with access can verify these requirements.

**EDIT**:
With the helpful pointer from TemplateRex to a draft of the standard, I can now say

**[N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) 25.4.4 [alg.merge]**

> 2 *Requires*: [...] The resulting range shall not overlap with either of
>   the original ranges.

Which confirms exactly what I was saying.

Comment: why don't you make this answer more precise by quoting from [the draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)? (hint: look for [alg.merge])

Comment: @TemplateRex thanks, I never knew where to find the standard, let alone quote it (even if it's just a draft).

Comment: +1 now :-) [Pro-tip from Stephan T. Lavavaj](http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1w7oky/getting_the_most_from_template_argument_deduction/cezlr4y) on how to quote form the Standard (see bottom of that comment).

Comment: Do you think that in most implementations the temporary buffer will be of the total size of the range or just a small part of it ?

Comment: @Vincent I assume that your question here comes from your previous one on sorting the remainder of a long vector. If your computation is memory-bound (i.e. you are already using more than 50% of memory), then I would suggest that you apply Jarod42's insertion sort solution: it is guaranteed in-place without buffers, at the price of quadratic complexity for sorting the remainder.

Comment: @Vincent I can't speak for "most" implementations but GCC 4.8.1 attempts to allocate a buffer the size of the input range (`std::distance(first,last)`).  Note that `std::get_temporary_buffer()` _can_ allocate less than requested and GCC 4.8.1 runs the more efficient version as long as its temporary buffer is not empty.  It seems that the size of the buffer affects how many times ranges must be moved around, the largest buffer only requires 1 copy and smaller ones may require more

Comment: Overlapping is now mentioned on cppreference.

Comment: Your complexity for std::merge() is wrong. It is
at most (last1 - first1) + (last2 - first2) - 1 comparisons not 
at most (last1 - first1) + (last2 - first2) + 1 comparisons. This matches std::inplace_merge() complexity where N = last2 - first1

Comment: @Vincent - If the ranges for inplace_merge are M & N, then the maximum amount of temporary memory required is min(M, N) * sizeof(element). So if you merging 2 sequences of sorted unsigned chars that were of size 1,000,000 elements and 5 elements, the maximum amount of temporary memory would be 5 characters. What makes this possible is implementations can merge forwards or backwards, taking care not to overwrite elements before they are needed. Most implementations of std::inplace_merge do this.

Comment: @SJHowe You're right, I checked the standard (draft) and it gives `-1` and not `+1`.